# How to reduce MaxUNSAT to MaxSAT?

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, reductions, satisfiability

Is it possible to reduce MaxUNSAT to [MaxSAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_satisfiability_problem) in a polynomial way ?

When considering the MaxSAT problem, one often considers also the `MinUNSAT` problem, which is almost the same. And for a propositional formula `f` in [CNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) it holds:

```
|f| = MaxSAT(f) + MinUNSAT(f)
```

where `|f|` is the number of clauses of f.

When considering `MaxUNSAT` and the corresponding `MinSAT` problem, the same relationship holds:

```
|f| = MaxUNSAT(f) + MinSAT(f)
```

Now, I was wondering if there is also a relationship between those two pairs, e.g. to reduce `MaxSAT` to `MaxUNSAT` or `MinSAT` (or the other way round) ?

Unfortunately, I could not figure out one by myself. And maybe there is none ?

**Update 1:** Inspired by Yuval Filmus's answer, I will give a reduction for my question.

**Reduction from MaxUNSAT to its corresponding decision problem:**

Let $\phi = {C_1, ..., C_m}$ a set of clauses over the variables $x_1, ..., x_n$, then it holds:
$$MaxUNSAT(\phi) = BinarySearch(0, |\phi|, MaxUNSAT(\phi, k) )$$
with

> `BinarySearch(start, end,` **CompareProcedure**( )`):`
>
> `Searches for the element` **e** `between` **start** `and` **end** `so that` **CompareProcedure**(**e**)=**true** `and` **CompareProcedures**(**e**+**1**)=**false**

and

$$MaxUNSAT(\phi, k) := \exists v\in\{0, 1\}^n:\sum_{i=1}^m 1 - I_v(C_i) \geq k$$
where $I_v$ is the interpretation of a propositional formula under assignment $v$.

**Reduction from decision problem $MaxUNSAT(\phi, k)$ to SAT:**

One can reduce the devision problem $MaxUNSAT(\phi, k)$ to the SAT problem by adding blocking variables to each clause and adding a cardinality constraint as propositional formula to limit the number of used clauses with help of the blocking variables.

I can describe this in more detail, if needed.

**Conculsion:**

One can reduce the MaxUNSAT problem to the SAT problem and then solve the SAT problem with the MaxSAT problem. This is a reduction that works in polynomial time.

Comment: I do not think that it is fair to change the question significantly after you receive an answer.

Comment: I do not think it has changed significantly. The question just changed from "How to reduce ... " to "How to reduce it in a more direct way". But if you want, I can break this question into two questions (open up a new question for the second one) to make things more clear/fair ?

Comment: I personally think so, because Yuval has already answered your original question and it seems that the purpose of your edit in revision 5 is to make his answer invalid.  Other people may think otherwise, though.

Comment: Yuval Filmus did not answer my question. He proved that there exists a reduction, but my question was not "Is it possible to reduce" but "How to reduce". So either way, his answer helped me to find a reduction, but did not provide a solution by itself. Therefore, my change did not touch his answer. But I understand the confusion of the change and to make things clear/fair again, I will open up a new question and rephrase this one to its original.

Answer (score 3):

Both MaxSAT and MaxUNSAT are NP-complete, and so can be reduced to one another. MaxSAT is NP-hard by (trivial) reduction from SAT. To see that MaxUNSAT is NP-hard, we follow Creignou [1] and reduce from MaxCUT. Given an instance $G=(V,E)$ of MaxCUT, consider the instance
$$ \bigwedge_{(x,y) \in E} (x \lor \lnot y) \land (\lnot x \lor y). $$
Each cut corresponds to a $0/1$ assignment to the vertices. If an edge $(x,y)$ is separated by a cut, then one of the two corresponding clauses will be unsatisfied, and otherwise none will be unsatisfied.

[1] Creignou, A dichotomy theorem for maximum generalized satisfiability problems, JCSS 51, 511-522 (1995).

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question with help of your answer. But you have to be careful with the term NP-complete when talking about optimization problems (which are not decision problems).