# How to reduce MaxUNSAT to MaxSAT in a (almost) direct way?

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, reductions, satisfiability

In question [How to reduce MaxUNSAT to MaxSAT?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4625/how-to-reduce-maxunsat-to-maxsat) I was asking, how to reduce the MaxUNSAT problem to MaxSAT. With help of the given answer I could give a polynomial reduction : $MaxUNSAT \leq decisionProblemMaxUNSAT \leq SAT \leq MaxSAT$.

**Question:** Is there a more direct reduction without much overhead from MaxUNSAT to MaxSAT (or to minUNSAT)?

Because the two problems are very similiar, it seems there is a more direct reduction, but I could not figure out one.

Something like $MaxUNSAT(\phi) = MaxSAT(\neg\phi)$ (which does not work).